# How to show JSON stringified prettier on Postman?

Tags: json, api, http, express, postman

On Postman, when the response has a JSON stringified, it looks like this:
(this is an example)

`"{\n  \"title\" : \"Forbidden\",\n  \"message\" : \"The user is not allowed to approve this post\",\n  \"status\" : 403\n}"`

How can I configure Postman to show me that response body prettier as when the response body is raw JSON?

**EDIT**

*Screenshot of the response*

[image: Screenshot of the response]

*Screenshot of the response's headers*

[image: Screenshot of the response's headers]

**EDIT 2**

My method is passing a JSON array. In fact, is an Express Response. When I use `response.send()` the JSON looks fine, but when I use `response.json()` it looks like a string

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Postman with the result and the result headers tab?

Comment: @MikaS Sure, I already edited the post with the screenshots :)

Comment: My suspicion was that content-type was something else than JSON, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Perhaps you are wrapping the JSON in a double set of ""? You could try looking in the Postman console and see if you find something there when you send the request. What happens when you send a GET request to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1? Same result, or is it only your own backend that gives this result?

Comment: Seems like your method passing JSON string and you need to pass JSON array instead

Comment: My method is passing a JSON array. In fact, is an Express Response. When I use response.send() the JSON looks fine, but when I use response.json it looks like a string @Div

Comment: Please add minimal example code which can reproduce the issue, we don't know what are you doing at server end